# Override nginx default 80 rule with SSL redirect rule

Tags: linux, nginx

I try to **override** nginx rules thinking what comes last replaces conflicting rules above them. In my case, I expect all insecure requests via HTTP should become HTTPS and reach the server that runs on 8000.

- However, on hitting HTTP version, the welcome page is rendered which is from **default.conf**.
- Is there a way to override it? Otherwise is it safe to comment out default.conf?

1. Port 80 to 443 Redirect     -  *not working*
2. Proxy pass 443 to 8000    -  *works*

Default rules in **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Custom rule in **/etc/nginx/conf.d/sslredirect.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wconnector.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Another custom rule which works fine **/etc/nginx/conf.d/wconnector.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wconnector.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }
}
```

`nginx -T` lists out confs in the order: default.conf, sslredirect.conf, wconnector.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of config files does not matter in nginx.
When it comes to requests sent to port 80 in your config, the important part is the `Host` header.

Depending on the `Host` header the respective server directive processes the request.
In case of `http://wconnector.com` the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/sslredirect.conf` server directive processes the request and shall properly redirect to `https://wconnector.com`

In case of any other host, the server directive in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` processes the request since it specifies `default_server` in `listen` for port `80`.

If you don't need the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` config file, it is safe to remove it altogether. nginx will start and process requests just fine.

Comment: btw my server isn't wconnector.com. I thought it's just an alias. if i remove default, will it work? or i should use proper hostname? i'll try this exact thing meanwhile.

Comment: for some reason, browser remembers the redirection. so after changing nginx config, i had to restart the browser and yeah it worked. removed default conf.

Comment: When you remove the `default.conf` file, the other file `sslredirect.conf` will be the only server listening on port 80. Therefore it will receive all requests and the server_name directive does not matter in this case. In production you want to configure the server_name to your specific domain though - if you have one.

Comment: this is good info, it works great on test instance, intuitively same should apply for prod (with domain name updated on `server_name` field). thanks @mike.